# Need alternate solution for DBMS_DEFER (Oracle 11g) after upgrade to Oracle 19C

Tags: oracle

Our application is upgrading from Oracle 11g to 19C. DBMS_DEFER which is used in our application is not supported in 19C and thus application package unit is getting invalid. Need help for alternate solution on the same.

Thanking all in advance.

Comment: This was removed as part of [Advance Replication being desupported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/desupported-features-oracle-database-12c-r2.html#GUID-32AC17C8-B9CB-44D5-B6B6-CB8D1AA8E307). Perhaps it would be more useful to edit your question to describe what you are trying to do, and why; maybe then someone can suggest an approach that doesn't rely on that package.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The application which uses oracle database 11g ,In some user defined packages it uses dbms_defer package for some remote call. Now the application is migrated bro oracle database 19c .so the package which calls dbms_defer is invalid as dbms_defer is not available in oracle 19c